# Changing postgres password for enduser

Tags: django, postgresql

is it possible to change an encrypted password with a sql query?

I have a user who for some reason can't log in and can't make her reset password recredentialing work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple: just use `ALTER ROLE` with the encrypted password.

```
ALTER ROLE luser PASSWORD 'md565b6fad0e85688f3f101065bc39552df';
```

Be aware that the password might end up in the log file if logging is configured appropriately.